# "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String]'"

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, cocoapods, swift3

I'm trying to get the pod "Swift-YouTube-Player" for CocoaPods working in Swift 3.0 and I am getting the following error for the code below (the errors points to the let pathComponents section).

*"Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String]'"*

```
public func videoIDFromYouTubeURL(_ videoURL: URL) -> String? {
    if let host = videoURL.host, let pathComponents = videoURL.pathComponents , pathComponents.count > 1 && host.hasSuffix("youtu.be") {
        return pathComponents[1]
    }
    return videoURL.queryStringComponents()["v"] as? String
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `videoURL.pathComponents` is not an Optional, so you have to break down the condition like this:

```
public func videoIDFromYouTubeURL(_ videoURL: URL) -> String? {
    if let host = videoURL.host {
        let pathComponents = videoURL.pathComponents 
        if pathComponents.count > 1 && host.hasSuffix("youtu.be") {
            return pathComponents[1]
        }
    } 
    return videoURL.queryStringComponents()["v"] as? String
}
```